# Mule session variables between async flows

Tags: mule

Mule allows using session variable using set-session-variable. I understand that the session variables behave more like ThreadLocal variables. Does it mean that the session variables are NOT copied over between asynchronous flows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are, and this is why they actually do not behave like ThreadLocal variables.

Comment: However..if a session variable is set in one async block, I am observing that it is not visible in another async block.

Comment: Isn't that what the question and answer are saying?

Answer (score 2):

Mule session variables are copied to flows along with the MuleMessage, even if it is Async flow.

More reference about session variables.

[Nice blog mentioning the usage of Mule Session variables.](http://blogs.mulesoft.org/using-mule-session-properties/)

Answer (score 0):

As other have said, session variables are copied to async flows but **remember** session variables are lost amid flows by outbound endpoints.

For ex: if you push your message to `JMS` queue, session variable is not copied over.

Comment: Good Point - Downvoter-please check the [Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368074) to understand the scenario in which the session variable gets lost when message is posted and retrieved from JMS queue... this is what [Learner](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1876644) is trying to convey in the comment above. Not sure why the session variable is lost though.

Answer (score 0):

Session vars will persist until execution and they can be accessed in async flows.