# Mule session-variable missing from the message, when reading from JMS Queue inside a Component

Tags: java, jms, session-variables, mule, endpoint

I have  requirement where in I need to read message from a JMS Queue  from inside a Component.

But during this process the session variables associated with the message are missing.
But the session variables are available when the same message is read from JMS:inbound-endpoint instead of from inside a component.

Here are my sample flows.

Main flow sets a session-variable into MuleMessage and posts it onto a JMS:outbound-endpoint

```
<flow name="main-flow" >
    <some  inbound>
    ...
    < Some processing >
    <set-session-variable .... />
    ...
    <jms:outbound-endpoint  queue="myQueue1">
</flow>
```

When the message is read from a JMS:inbound-endpoint   the session variable can be seen in the message.

```
<flow name="second-flow" >
    <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="myQueue1" />

    <logger level="INFO" />
    ...
    <  some processing />   
</flow>
```

But when the message is read from the Component polling the JMS:queue  the session variable is missing.

```
<flow name="third-flow" >
    <quartz:inbound-endpoint  repeat-interval="5 mins" />
    ....
    <component>
        <spring-object bean="MyComponent"/>
    </component>
    ....
</flow>
```

MyComponent class's  onCall method has the following code to read from the JMS queue.

```
    String reqURL = "jms://" + queueName ;
    muleMessage = eventContext.requestEvent(reqURL, 1000);
```

But the session variable is not present in the Mule Message.

Comment: Is the Mule session property inbound header visible in the `muleMessage`?

Comment: Nope.I verified it in the Queue. I didn't see the property as Inbound.

Comment: If the serialized Mule session is not stored in the JMS message properties, how come it works with a JMS inbound endpoint? I'm confused here.

Comment: I could see a Property Named   MULE_SESSION as Inbound property of  the Message in the Queue as well as after reading from the Queue.

Comment: Mmmh... I think it should be deserialized by `eventContext.requestEvent` then. Maybe a bug :( You could try using http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.4.0/apidocs/index.html?org/mule/session/SerializeAndEncodeSessionHandler.html to deserialize it yourself.

Comment: Will try it on my own. It seems it is a bug.